# Make Jupyter Notebook script work 1 time per hour

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a Jupyter Notebook. Here is just a simplified example.

```
#Parsing the website
def parse_website_function(url):
  return(value,value2)

#Making some calculations(hypothesis)
def linear_model(value, value2):
  return(calculations)

#Jot down calculations to csv file     
pd.to_csv(calculations)
```

I would like to know how to make it work every hour and enable to rewrite(add new rows) to  csv time series data in the same output file. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, is there a reason why you want to keep the notebook running to do this? Like would you be able to just have a simple python script that parses the website and then writes to a pdf file? If you want to run the notebook each hour, you will need to either start and stop a jupyter process every hour, and seems like you could get the same result with just a script. If you can use a simple python script, then you can just add a `cron` job to the scheduler on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really basic way to do this would be to just make the program sleep for 3600 seconds.

For example this would make your program pause for 1 hour:

```
import time
time.sleep(3600)
```